# android gridlayout implementation

Tags: android, responsive-design

I'm trying to develop one new project. My client wants me to design like current GooglePlay design (block design per attach). That's why I'm confused whether `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>` will be useful or not for implement such block design featured. If not, please let me know how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html. Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I hope this helps. It uses GridView instead of GridLayout. A good post about that can be found [GridView VS GridLayout in Android Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307218/gridview-vs-gridlayout-in-android-apps)

**Edit:** Here is my example

***Note:*** Most of this is taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html. The ImageAdapter used in GridViewExample is taken directly from there as are the pictures used.

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Page Title" />

    <!-- Insert some sort of scrolling if desired -->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Grid 1 Title" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:columnWidth="50dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Grid 2 Title" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:columnWidth="50dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" />         
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Main Activity:

```
package com.example.gridviewdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GridViewExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.gridview_example);

        GridView gridView1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(GridViewExample.this, "1: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        GridView gridView2 = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        gridView2.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
                Toast.makeText(GridViewExample.this, "2: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Produces: 
[image]
It looks like the layout is a little off on a tablet, but with some work I am sure that can be fixed

Comment: I've already looked it up but has not got any idea to implement it yet.

Comment: If your goal is to get it to look like the screen shots, wouldn't it be possible to use a combination of GridView's and TextView's inside a LinearLayout?

Comment: any example can you more provide? By the way, 1 vote up.

Comment: I will give it a shot, but may take a little while - and thanks

Comment: Just posted the edit. I think this is what you are looking for. You can scroll vertically within the GridView and select each picture individually.