# How does Android Play Store list Applications?

Tags: android, performance, android-webview

I am trying to list some items in a way very similar to Play Store, currently I am using a Webview and managed to do something similar looking, but performance wise it is very slow.

I'm wondering if Play Store also uses a Webview and gets data from a mobile website like I did, or Play Store uses some sort of widget/view/component to achieve this task, possibly natively. It seems on slow or zero internet connection, the application frames+names are still displayed, and only the images do a lazy load, possibly contributing to much smoother application performance while still capable of listing lots of apps on scrooldown. Here is the Play Store page I'm trying to emulate on my application:

[image]

Comment: use `apktool` and find out what it uses

Comment: Its probably a custom GridView!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WA5U_hBw544) that explains the theory behind the new Google Play design. No code though. But it is very interesting.

Basically they are using Cards as their main building blocks.

[image: Card]

Cards are organized into clusters.

[image: Clusters]

And everythings rests on top of a Canvas.

[image: Canvas]

You can check out the presentation slides [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+NickButcher/posts/5kYq29PedqD).

Comment: May I ask, how are Cards updated based on online resources dynamically?

Comment: New slides from this year's AnDevCon can be found here (they also include some code) https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1KjveCvv1ffr0GyUAMRE-zd5Hg3vqSHzDAZJmAmecxYA/edit

Comment: Which language they are using?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest to implement this kind of screen with a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) Tutorials for using it (there are tons of others too):

- http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/
- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

There is also a GridLayout in Android. The difference between the two components is explained clearly in this post: [GridView VS GridLayout in Android Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307218/gridview-vs-gridlayout-in-android-apps)

Comment: I will look into this, I've done further research based on Benito's answer and you're right. May I know how do these cards get updated from online resources dynamically?