# GridView and GridLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridlayout

I trying to add child views for GridView in xml file but it is giving error and it working fine with GridLayout. so I want know ..
What is difference b/w GridView and GridLayout in android ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307218/gridview-vs-gridlayout-in-android-apps

Answer (score 12):

The basic difference is that GridView is a scrollable View like ListView, and GridLayout is a layout. Both look the same but GridView is scrollable

According to the documentation for [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), the formal definition is the following:

> **GridView**
>
> GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional,
>   scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the
>   layout using a ListAdapter.

And the definition for GridLayout, from the same [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html)

> **GridLayout**
>
> A layout that places its children in a rectangular grid.
>
> The grid is composed of a set of infinitely thin lines that separate
>   the viewing area into cells. Throughout the API, grid lines are
>   referenced by grid indices. A grid with N columns has N + 1 grid
>   indices that run from 0 through N inclusive. Regardless of how
>   GridLayout is configured, grid index 0 is fixed to the leading edge of
>   the container and grid index N is fixed to its trailing edge (after
>   padding is taken into account).