# android grid layout allignment

Tags: android, layout, grid

at the moment i'm building schedule view and i have one problem. how to make grid layout take all the screen space equally?

as you can see (column), friday takes up all the space that's left. same with hours (rows), if the screen is bigger, last one will takes all the space. (damn, cannot upload pictures, because i dont have enough rep)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:text="FONTYS LOGO"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="12"
    android:columnCount="15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/firstLessonTextView"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="8" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="9" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="11"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="11" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="12" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="13"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="13" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="08.45"

        android:id="@+id/firstLessonTimeTextView"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="09.35"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10.45"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="11.35"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12.25"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="13.15"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="14.05"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="15.15"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="8" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="16.05"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="9" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="16.55"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView23"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="18.00"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="11" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="18.50"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView25"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="12" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20.00"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="13" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mon"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/gradesDateMondayID"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tue"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/gradesDateTuesdayID"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wed"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/gradesDateWednesdayID"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Thu"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/gradesDateThursdayID"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fri"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_row="10"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/gradesDateFridayID"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_row="11"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</GridLayout>
```

parameters on all textviews are the same. all 15colums and 12 rows are used. hope you can help me

Comment: please check my answer , and if be useful , accept it

Answer (score 0):

the solution is :

in your layout , you should declare :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_dandan_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:listSelector="#0099f1"
        android:divider="@drawable/parand_line_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i praper some tutorial for you , that be useful :

[AndroidHive Tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2012%2F02%2Fandroid-gridview-layout-tutorial%2F&ei=yOgVVa-ZL4bnaKCUgMgG&usg=AFQjCNEyanr82WA8KsC5oOpNMh8WHivGmg&sig2=SETj_Wsh1_gGJ6LdjOHz9w&bvm=bv.89381419,d.d2s)

[Mkyong Tutorial , That be Very Clear](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mkyong.com%2Fandroid%2Fandroid-gridview-example%2F&ei=yOgVVa-ZL4bnaKCUgMgG&usg=AFQjCNHGSjP6tV5oIj-xNX2PmmPn5iDGZg&sig2=W6IgMwtt_03EDH7jNetPUg&bvm=bv.89381419,d.d2s)

**update**

you need something like this :

[image]

Comment: Hi Adnan, the question is about `GridLayout`.

Comment: hey, im not sure i can make schedule with gridview :/

Comment: do you want to create calendar layout ?

Comment: just copy paste code in your android studio and you will see the problem im getting. im creating timetable of the week :) it can be related  halfly on calendar i suppose.

Comment: @Vikram yeah . but gridLayout for 12*15 cells , not useful . zeromaro have same 12*15 textView . and why use gridLayout ???

Comment: because i have to parse my classes to the schedule. in this case gridlayout which i can assign where which class should go :)

Comment: i'll try to read on on that and try to make it later on! i'd like to hear more suggestions as well if possible! :)

Comment: please , check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307218/gridview-vs-gridlayout-in-android-apps