# What is better to use and the difference between GridLayout and GridView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, layout

Can someone explain to me the differences? Which would be better to use for which situation.

Answer (score 1):

A [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView) is a ViewGroup that displays items in two-dimensional scrolling grid. The items in the grid come from the ListAdapter associated with this view.

This is what you'd want to use (keep using). Because a GridView gets its data from a ListAdapter, the only data loaded in memory will be the one displayed on screen. GridViews, much like ListViews reuse and recycle their views for better performance.

Whereas a [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) is a layout that places its children in a rectangular grid.

It was introduced in API level 14, and was recently backported in the Support Library. Its main purpose is to solve alignment and performance problems in other layouts. Check out this [tutorial](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) if you want to learn more about GridLayout.

Comment: Stolen answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11307615/5033470

Comment: Blud thinks hes the popo lmao @GreysonYee